# Find $\epsilon(n)$ such that $\sum\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon(n)}}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know that the $p$-series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p}$$ converges if $p>1$ an diverges if $p\leq 1$. Now i was given this seemingly impossible problem:

Find positive sequence $\epsilon(n)$ which monotonically converges to $0$ such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon(n)}}$$
converges.
Basically, we need something converging to $0$ really really slow, so that $1+\epsilon(n)$ can make the series converge and I ran out of ideas after trying $\epsilon(n)=1/n^a,\epsilon(n)=1/\ln(n)$ or $\epsilon(n)=\pi/2-\arctan(n)$. Can someone give some ideas?

Comment: An interesting problem. Could you share the source?

Comment: It's been proposed by my teacher in analysis class. No real electronic source.

Comment: I let $e(n) = 1/\ln \ln n$ and used Maple to perform the integral test.  It couldn't find an antiderivative, but it says numerically that the integral from $3$ to $\infty$ is about $0,38,$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^a(n)}$ is convergent for $a>1$ and
$$\frac{1}{n\ln^a(n)}=\frac{1}{ne^{a\ln(\ln(n))}}=\frac{1}{n^{1+a\frac{\ln(\ln(n))}{\ln(n)}}}.$$

Answer (score 4):

By Cauchy condensation test we obtaint the condensed series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^{n+n\epsilon(2^n)}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n\epsilon(2n)}}$$

then we need $n\epsilon(2^n) \to \infty$ and therefore we are looking for a monotonic sequence

$$\epsilon(n)=\frac{\delta(n)}{\log n}\to 0$$

such that $\delta(2^n)\to \infty$, as for example

- $\delta(n)=\ln \ln n$
- $\delta(n)=\ln^p n \quad 0<p<1$

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but why should $n\epsilon(2^n)\rightarrow \infty$ make the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n\epsilon(2^n)}}$$ converge?

Comment: @MichalDvořák It is a necessary condition which can guide to find such sequences.

Comment: Well, i get the point that the summand must go to $0$ with $n\to\infty$, but that doesn't necesarily mean that $\sum a_n$ converges. Rather the converse is always true.

Comment: @MichalDvořák For example for $n\epsilon(2^n)=\ln n$ it doesn't converge.

Comment: Yup, that's clear, but your argument goes like... "If $n\epsilon(2^n)\rightarrow \infty$ that is $\frac{1}{2^{n\epsilon(2^n)}}\rightarrow 0$, then the series converges. But if some $a_n\rightarrow 0$, it doesn't necesarrily mean that $\sum a_n$ converges. Probably your solution is right, just what you wrote sounds weird for me.

Comment: @MichalDvořák Yes I get your point and maybe what I've wrote that not in a proper way. My point is that the given series converges $\iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n\epsilon(2n)}}$ and for that it is necessary (but not sufficient) that $n\epsilon(2n)\to \infty$. Maybe the part on $\delta$ needs to be fixed.